# Configuring pom.xml to work with tomee

Tags: maven, apache-tomee

Well, i'm starting now with tomee, my pom.xml was configured to use with tomcat. So, i don't have sure what i have to remove or add to work with tomee with the followings technologies: JPA, CDI, EJB, HIBERNATE.

I configured my pom.xml in this way:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>cedoc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cedoc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- FOR TOMEE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0-6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FOR TOMEE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.jwebbuild</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwebbuild</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JASPER REPORT IMPORTS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- FIM JASPER RESPORT IMPORTS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.11-M1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>java.net2.m2</id>
            <name>Java.net m2 repo</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>cedoc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

But i got some errors, see:

when start server i got error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
```

What is the exactly libs i have to add in pom.xml to use tomee and what scope ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing a Vanilla JavaEE application, you **do not** need this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Why is that? Because TomEE implements the JavaEE standard without anything else. If you are tying your application to TomEE you're not using it correctly!

Next, you didn't say what version of TomEE you are using, but these dependencies are suspect:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

TomEE 1.7.4 is JavaEE6 compatible, so JSF 2.2 won't work, unless you replace the MyFaces 2.1 jars in the lib directory with the latest MyFaces 2.2 jars. You ARE correct in using them as provided dependencies, so don't change that. The other option is to use TomEE 7, which hasn't been released, but provides JavaEE 7 compatibility.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

^ This should be removed completely. The vanilla JavaEE jar provides those interfaces.

Ok, so at a minimum you'll have to fix these issues before you can continue. Once you do that, report back in another question any further issues if you have them. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. With this i can go on. What is "vanilla javaEE", i didnt understand this expression

Comment: It refers to your code development style. Only use classes and features that are in JSRs and official JavaEE specifications. This keeps you from getting locked into a vendor.

Comment: if you don't mind, and you feel I deserve it, please check my solution as the answer ;) StackOverflow courtesy